# How to access API from Postman with containerized app deployed in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I have created a sample API application with Node and Express to be containerized and deployed into Azure Kubernetes Services (AKS). However, I was unable to access the API endpoint through the external API generated from the service.yml that was deployed.

I have made use of deployment center within AKS to deploy my application to AKS and generate the relevant deployment.yml and service.yml. The following is the services running containing the external IP.

[image]

The following is the response from postman. I have tried with or without port number and ip address from `kubectl get endpoints` but to no avail. The request will timeout eventually and unable to access the api.

[image]

The following is the dockerfile config

[image]

I have tried searching around for solutions, how it was not possible to resolve. I would greatly appreciate if you have encountered similar issues and able to share your experience, thank you.

Comment: Can you please verify that you can access the **API** from within the cluster.

Comment: Can you share your dockerfile?

Comment: @Bimal I have attached the dockerfile screenshot

Comment: @HimadriGanguly I am new to AKS, how do I test out the API from within the cluster?

Comment: Did you try with port `30837`? Looks like you are forwarding the port.

Comment: @Bimal Yes, I have tried. I can't connect to the API

Comment: @RichardRodjues were you able to finally solve your problem or you still require some?

Comment: @thomas I was able to resolve my problem, thank you

Answer (score 2):

From client machine where **kubectl** is installed do

```
kubectl get pods -o wide -n restapicluster5ca2
```

this will give you all the pods with the ip of the Pods

```
kubectl describe svc restapicluster-bb91 -n restapicluster5ca2
```

this will give details about the **service** and then check **LoadBalancer Ingress:** for the external IP address, **Port:** for the port to access, **TargetPort:** the port on the containers to access i.e **5000** in your case, **Endpoints:** to verify if all IP of the pod with correct port i.e **5000** is displaying or not.

Log into any of the machines in the AKS cluster do the following

```
curl [CLUSTER-IP]:[PORT]/api/posts i.e curl 10.-.-.67:5000
```

check if you get the response.

For reference to use **kubectl** locally with **AKS** cluster check the links below

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: Then something is wrong with the service or the pods are not running or the pods are exposing the service on a different port. Check step by step. Start from the pod/deployment then the service.

Comment: Yes I believe so too. All the while I was maunually creating my own deployment and service yaml files. But I cam across this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-on-kubernetes#deploy-the-image-to-your-kubernetes-cluster and after running the 2 kubectl commands I managed to expose the port. Thank you for your help anyways!

Comment: @RichardRodjues were you able to finally solve your problem or you still require some help?

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you need to bring ingress in front of your service. Folks use NgInx etc. for that.

If you want to stay "pure" Azure you could use [AGIC - Application Gateway Ingress Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-overview) and annotate your service to have it exposed over AppGw. You could also spin up your own custom AppGw and hook it up with the AKS Service/LoadBalancer IP.

Comment: but your are saying that with just the LoadBalancer IP it is not possible to access the service? Just want to clarify for my knowledge. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry - did not look thoroughly enough at your screen shot. Did you try the Load Balancer´s External IP with port 5000? There seems to be some kind of external exposure on this service.

Comment: this is not my issue I am also trying to help by solving the issue so that I can enhance my knowledge as well. Learning by sharing knowledge. LOL